# I am trying to access secure website where right button click is disabled. by using selenium Xpath cannot click on elements

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

The website which for which I am trying to do automation is a secure website where some functions like right clicking have been disabled. I am using the exact xpath for the login input field but it is not working. My Xpath is as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'input')]")).sendKeys("Aa12");
```

Comment: Do you see html code when open the chrome dev tools (Ctrl+Shift+I)?

Comment: Yes i did to find out xpath.

Comment: Sorry, are you getting any error message when try to run the code? And is it possible to share the html of the element that you are trying to click. FYI, click() will simulate the left mouse click not right, so you should be good with .click().

Comment: this is my html code   <input class="input" type="text" name="username" maxlength="16" id="login_username">

Comment: Did you got any error message? And have you tried with `//input[@id='login_username']`? The xpath you used is not so promising as there might be another input element with `xxx input yyy` which will match with the xpath that you used.

Comment: yes i tried //input[@id='login_username'] and i didn't get any error message. with selenium ide i can automate but not selenium webdriver.

Comment: [Join chat with supputuri here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192695/discussion-between-supputuri-and-user10146017)

Comment: please click on the link above to join the chat.

Comment: So have you found a solution?  What exactly do you mean by "it is not working"--are you getting an error? Does it just not input the text?

Comment: by selenium webdriver i can just load the website, i cannot do anything else no click, no text enter nothing . This happening with one website which appears as  Not secure warning

Comment: You haven't provided the URL or the relevant HTML. I'm not sure how we are supposed to determine what the problem is with your locator, etc. Also "not working" is not very descriptive... does it throw an error/exception message (if so post it) or ??? You need to better describe the problem, your code, error messages, etc.

Comment: my URL is like this https://192.168.0.... and i am using intranet to access this web application.Not working means i cannot access any webelement through selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

SeeTest provides a way for opening the developer tools even in such cases.
They also have different versions of chrome in which you can try your scenario.
[Their documentation](https://docs.experitest.com/display/LT/Open+developer+tools) might help you more on this.